# htop - See/Filter all the instances of a binary

Tags: output, filter, htop

I have a binary that I will be running multiple times in parallel, each instance executed with different input from the command line.
I wanted htop to list only these processes so that I can compare the usage of memory based on the cli inputs. 
I tried [htop -p ] but this lists only one process even if I give muliple process ids as the input.
Is there any way to get the output with input being multiple process IDs or with the part of the process name.

Example as I hope to see in htop:

```
  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
  356 root       20   0 52952  7980  6632 S  0.0  0.8  0:00.00 ./test 1
  357 root       20   0 2356   416   352  S  0.0  0.8  0:00.00 ./test 2
  358 root       20   0 2356   332   268  S  0.0  0.8  0:00.00 ./test 3
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `htop` takes multiple pids in the form `-p PID,PID...`.  Was that what you typed?

Comment: @JigglyNaga I tried giving the `PID` separated by a space but the output was only reflecting the process pointed by the first `PID`. I had not tried `,` I checked that now and it is working, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man htop`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/htop/htop.1.en.html):

```
F4, \
    Incremental  process  filtering:  type  in  part  of  a process command line and only
    processes whose names match will be shown. To  cancel  filtering,  enter  the  Filter
    option again and press Esc.
```

So, once you start `htop`, type `\test` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to filter in only commands containing `test`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I did try that and it is working, thanks!